# when we drag the item out of the scope it is moving with cursor only in articulation3.How to fix this issue.?

Tags: articulate-storyline

I tried by changing the properties of that triggers and re-built the slide also.
Even the issue is not resolved.Can anyone help me on this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out below link
u get solution

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/cool-websites/control-mouse-with-keyboard/